# ggplot2: x-axis extreme-right tick-label clipped after insetting legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

After insetting the legend, the x-axis extreme-right tick-label ("400") is clipped. Two solutions I found for clipping don't work.
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
textsize=12
o2b <- colorRampPalette(c("brown", "orange"))(4)

p <- theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
           panel.background=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), 
           plot.title=element_blank(), 
           legend.background=element_blank(), legend.key=element_blank(), legend.position=c(1,1), 
           legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.text=element_text(size=textsize), legend.title=element_text(size=textsize), 
           axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), axis.text=element_text(size=textsize, colour="black"), 
           axis.title=element_text(size=textsize))

p1 <- ggplot(temp1, aes(x=rank, y=rhh, colour=factor(naics_level))) + p + geom_point(shape=1, size=2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=o2b) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title="Niveau de NAICS", title.position = "left", reverse=T)) +  
  labs(x="Rang des MSA", y="Diversité sectorielle basée sur l'emploi en 2015")

# Turn off clipping
library(grid)

# Neither of the two following commands makes a difference
gt <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))

gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

Comment: Try with `plot.margin` inside `theme`

Comment: Thanks @MikolajM. `plot.margin = unit(c(5.5,12,5.5,5.5), "pt")` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @MikolajM's suggestion, the simple solution is:

```
library(ggplot2)
textsize=12
o2b <- colorRampPalette(c("brown", "orange"))(4)

p <- theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
           panel.background=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), 
           plot.title=element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(5.5,12,5.5,5.5), "pt"), 
           legend.background=element_blank(), legend.key=element_blank(), legend.position=c(1,1), 
           legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.text=element_text(size=textsize), legend.title=element_text(size=textsize), 
           axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), axis.text=element_text(size=textsize, colour="black"), 
           axis.title=element_text(size=textsize))

p1 <- ggplot(temp1, aes(x=rank, y=rhh, colour=factor(naics_level))) + p + geom_point(shape=1, size=2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=o2b) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title="Niveau de NAICS", title.position = "left", reverse=T)) +  
  labs(x="Rang des MSA", y="Diversité sectorielle basée sur l'emploi en 2015")
```

Turning off clipping becomes irrelevant.